# DraftJS. Wrap up custom HTML tag with a custom Component

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins, react-draft-wysiwyg

Trying to implement smth similar with **pure** Draft.js:

[image: Gmail UI for hidden blocks]

To be more precise, i want to have these hidden blocks of original message(s) that are editable and expandable by clicking three-dots icon

So, after some research i found out there are [Custom Block Rendering](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map) and [Custom Block Components](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components), so i'm trying to extend the blockRenderMap with OriginalMessage component:

```js
const OriginalMessage = ({ children }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const toggleExpanded = () => setExpanded(!expanded);

  return (
    <div>
      <span style={{ display: 'inline-block', padding: 4 }} onClick={toggleExpanded}>
        ...
      </span>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const blockRenderMap = Immutable.Map({
  original: {
    element: 'original',
    wrapper: <OriginalMessage />,
  },
});

const extendedBlockRenderMap = DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap.merge(blockRenderMap);

...


// rendering the Editor

<Editor
  ...
  blockRenderMap={extendedBlockRenderMap}
/>
```

so, these are probably working pieces of code, and idea is - i need to parse following HTML into respective and recognizable blocks:

```html
<p>For example, this is a template that every new email has</p>
<p>Here we have a signature</p>
<original>A lot of HTML here that includes previous messages blockquotes etc</original>
```

i use `html-to-draftjs` to get parse this html into blocks:

```js
const blocksFromHTML = htmlToDraft(content, nodeName => {
  if (nodeName === 'original') {
    return {
      type: 'original',
      mutability: 'MUTABLE',
      data: {},
    };
  }
});

// setting new State

const newEditorState = EditorState.createWithContent(
  ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
  ),
  decorator,
);

setEditorState(newEditorState);
```

But when i check the block that suppose to have `original` type, the type is `unstyled`.

The question is - how to make Editor recognise `<original>` tag as a block that needs to be customly rendered?

btw, not sure that it's the right approach to solve the issue - any help or advice appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `Document.execCommand()` and write your own component from scratch.
Then you will be able to do whatever you wish. Have a look at this example solving your issue, https://codepen.io/Nagibaba/pen/oNBQXgp